# Elements side by side not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I got a menu with a list in my application, i want put a circle in side of the text, but in firefox the div with the circle not appear correctly. What i need to do for this work well in firefox?

[List elements in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnTZt.png)

[List elements in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpnmH.png)

CSS of the div element

```
#circulo-inativo {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #F05A29;
}
```

Html list

```
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu festival-dropdown" aria-labelledby="festivalSelector">
                    <li><a href="/admin/festivals">Ver todos festivais</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="http://fosfobox.lvh.me:3009/admin">test <div id="circulo-ativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://novo2.lvh.me:3009/admin">novo2 <div id="circulo-ativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://novo1.lvh.me:3009/admin">FESTIVAL DE VERÃO DE SALVADOR BAHIA <div id="circulo-ativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://asdasasd.lvh.me:3009/admin">dadsad <div id="circulo-inativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://dasdsa.lvh.me:3009/admin">dasdas <div id="circulo-inativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://313123.lvh.me:3009/admin">132312 <div id="circulo-inativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://eweqw.lvh.me:3009/admin">nvo teste <div id="circulo-inativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://festtest.lvh.me:3009/admin">Festival Teste <div id="circulo-inativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://sotrackboa.lvh.me:3009/admin">Só Track Boa <div id="circulo-inativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://promotersdelirium.lvh.me:3009/admin">Promoters Delirium <div id="circulo-inativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://delirium.lvh.me:3009/admin">Delirium <div id="circulo-inativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                        <li><a href="http://radiola.lvh.me:3009/admin">Radiola <div id="circulo-inativo"> </div>

                         </a>

                        </li><td class="ativo"></td>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="festival-dropdown__new-festival"><a href="/admin/festivals/new">Criar novo festival</a></li>
                  </ul>
```

Comment: We need to see all the relevant code so that we have a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: What is missing? I put two pictures with the behaviours in both browsers and the code i used.